# How to know when docker CMD is done?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I was wondering if anyone knew if it is possible to know when a docker CMD is done executing?

I initially have tried putting an ENTRYPOINT command after the CMD but it runs immediately when you run the docker container.

Also, if this can only be done with docker-compose that would be fine as well if there is a way to know when the command: is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two answers are indeed correct but don't directly answer your questions. Once the `CMD` is finished the container will exit, but will still exist on your host until it's removed.

Assuming you started the `docker run` or `docker-compose up` with a `-d` so that they run in the background (detached):

- `docker container ps` only shows running containers, so once it's exited then `docker container ps -a` will show it.
- `docker-compose ps` shows the status of all compose services, including stopped containers.

Answer (score 5):

The container stops and exits once the `CMD` has finished running.

You can use:

`$ docker wait [container name/id]`

to wait on a container to stop. If the container is already stopped, this command will return immediately. Otherwise, it'll wait until the container finishes its work, or is otherwise stopped.

---

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/wait/

> Block until one or more containers stop, then print their exit codes

Answer (score 2):

The Docker `CMD` will not be done until the container is stopped/killed. The `CMD` instruction is a way start the main process that will run inside the container. This process will keep running until the
container is stopped or killed.

Inside the Dockerfile, it doesn't matter where you put the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` instruction. When you include both and `ENTYPOINT` and `CMD` instructions inside the same dockerfile, the `CMD` will be appended to the `ENTRYPOINT` command as arguments.

Comment: The link has a typo and It also seems to be broken :(